# SQL server stops sending db mails in sql server 2014

Tags: sql-server, dbmail

We are facing the issue with DB mails in sql server 2014.

Suddenly, it stops sending emails to users stating UNSENT status in msdb.dbo.sysmail_allitems.

Please help.

Comment: Have a look at the logs for the failed items in `msdb.dbo.sysmail_event_log`. What kind of errors are you getting in the `description` column?

Answer (score 1):

Check out if someone disable broker or disable sending e-mail. These two queries should return 1.

```
SELECT value_in_use
FROM sys.configurations
WHERE name = 'Database Mail XPs';

SELECT is_broker_enabled 
FROM sys.databases 
WHERE name='MSDB';
```

Is there records in the transmission queue? No record means good. If there is a record, pay attention on field transmission_status. This is written the reason this message is on the queue. This is generally an error message explaining why sending the message failed.

```
select * from msdb.sys.transmission_queue ;
```

Try cleaning 'ExternalMailQueue'

```
WHILE EXISTS
(
    SELECT 'ExternalMailQueue' AS ServiceBrokerQueueName, 
           *
    FROM [msdb].[dbo].[ExternalMailQueue]
)
    BEGIN
        WAITFOR(
        RECEIVE TOP (1) conversation_group_id FROM [ExternalMailQueue]), TIMEOUT 1000;
    END;
```